# Linking gtest with glog

Tags: googletest, glog

Is there a way to get the ouput of gtest in a log file generated by glog ? Ideally it would stream with severity error when tests fail and info otherwise. I could do it manually but I was wondering if this can be done easily with existing tools.

I am only interested in glog outputs, not XML generated by gtest using `RecordProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [custom listener](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Extending_Google_Test_by_Handling_Test_Events) that will log test failures. You can see how it's doen in the Google Test [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample9_unittest.cc).